# Subseting Matrix in R

Tags: r

So basically which days over both weeks were either less than 0 or more than 0

```
             [,1]  [,2]
M            -5    -5
T             8    -9
W            -4     9
Th            6     8
F             7    -3
```

```
# however my output is this
   [,1] [,2]  #I want the row label M, how do I do that?
   -1    -5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `drop = FALSE` to avoid dropping the dimensions as the default usage is

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

when there is a single row as output, the `drop = TRUE` will drops the dimensions to return a `vector`

```
diff[diff[, "Week1"] <0 & diff[, "Week2" ]< 0, , drop = FALSE]
#.       Week1 Week2
#Monday    -1    -5
```

Or another option is `Reduce`

```
diff[Reduce(`&`, asplit(diff > 0, 2)), , drop = FALSE]
#         Week1 Week2
#Thursday     4     5
```

NOTE: `diff` is a function name.  It is better to name object identifiers with different names

---

We could also use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
diff %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    filter(across(starts_with('Week'), `>`, 0))
 #       rn Week1 Week2
 #1 Thursday     4     5
```

#### data

```
diff <- structure(c(-1L, 8L, -3L, 4L, 7L, -5L, -4L, 9L, 5L, -2L), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday"), c("Week1", "Week2")))
```

Comment: Can you show the dput of the data.  I thought it is a `matrix`

Comment: It is a matrix!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowSums` to get rows with both the weeks less than 0 or above 0.

```
under <- diff[rowSums(diff > 0) == 0, , drop = FALSE]
over <- diff[rowSums(diff < 0) == 0, , drop = FALSE]
under

#       Week1 Week2
#Monday    -1    -5

over
#         Week1 Week2
#Thursday     4     5
```